# Why do I get different results when compiling the same code with different ide?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, avr, adc, atmel-studio

I have a basic code about reading true rms.I compiled the same code with arduino ide and atmel studio, then ran it in a proteus simulation.I'm trying to measure how long the read_rms() function takes.

My mcu:attiny84

1.experiment)I have added board to arduino ide with board manager.And I chose attiny84 and internal 1Mhz from tools menu in arduino menu.
The result was that the read_rms() function took 23.25 milliseconds.

2.experiment)I compiled the same code without any changes in Atmel Studio.Device,attiny84 selected.
The result was that the read_rms() function took 44 milliseconds.

44 miliseconds vs 23.25 miliseconds. Why?

Note:The following settings are selected in the proteus.Internal RC Osc. 8 Mhz,and CKDIV8=Programmed.

My code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>   
const uint8_t muxbits = 1<<MUX3 | 1<<MUX2 | 1<<MUX1 | 1<<MUX0;   


void adc_init()
{
    ADMUX = 0;    //Vcc_ref_
    ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0); //adc_enable_and_prescaler_8_ 125000 Hz (1000000/8)
    //first_try
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC)) != 0);
}

uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t channel)  
{
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & ~muxbits) | channel;
    // start_single_convertion
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    
    // wait for conversion to complete
    while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC)) != 0);
    
    return (ADC);
}
   
double read_rms()
{
    uint16_t i=0;
    uint16_t a_data=0;
    uint32_t sum=0;
    float avarage=0;
    double rms=0;
    for(i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        a_data=adc_read(1);
        
        sum=sum+(a_data*a_data);
    }
    avarage=(float)sum/200;
    rms=sqrt((double)avarage);
    
    
    return rms;
    
}


int main(void)
{
    
    DDRA|=(1<<7);
    PORTA &=~ (1<<7);       
    adc_init();

    while(1)
    {

    read_rms();    
    PORTA ^= (1<<7);// TOOGLE_PA7   for_measure_time_of_read_rms()_with_oscilloscope
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell. Maybe Atmel studio is using actual double-precision values for `double` whereas Arduino uses only `float` (single precision).

Comment: It's not impossible to tell. You could compare the assembler generated by both. I'm not very familiar with AVR assembler, so I wouldn't be the best choice to do that analysis, but  I'm sure somebody on this board could suss it out.

Comment: You could also get something of a fuzzy confirmation on whether `float` vs `double` is responsible by just altering your code to make use of `float` types everywhere.  This includes using `sqrtf` rather than `sqrt`.  As said, there may still be other differences, so the timing results may not completely converge.

Answer (score 1):

Different compilers produce different machine code.

As Majenko pointed out, the Arduino IDE's compiler, which happens to be GCC, uses `float` even when you write `double`.

The Atmel Studio creates `double` for `double`, using twice as much bits.

Calculating with more bits takes longer.

Comment: I did float.the result is the same again.And I did sqrtf instead of sqrt.

Comment: Did you look into the generated assembly? There might be some implicit conversions to `double`, or Atmel's compiler uses the standard `sqrt()` even for `sqrtf()`.

Comment: no I haven't examined.But,Why would there be such a thing?Instead of sqrt I typed sqrtf because I didn't want to use double numbers unnecessarily. As for the main problem, I think it's related to compiler configurations. But I haven't figured it out yet.